# Submit a form with multiple submit buttons in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

There is ONE input element, whose value is given by the user.
and 3 buttons, whose values are coming from the states.

So when I put intput value as "11" and press SUBMIT1 button,
then the output in console should be
  `{userId: "11", submit1: "1"}`

Instead I get the whole submit values too

```
{userId: "11", submit1: "1", submit2: "2", submit3: "3"}
```

Also, I got a response error (LINE NUMBER 23) :
I am trying to send one INPUT value and ONE submit value (of the button that was clicked..)

PostForm.jsx file

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
class PostForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      userId: "",
      submit1: "1",
      submit2: "2",
      submit3: "3"
    };
  }

  changeHandler = e => {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  submitHandler = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.state);
    axios
      .post(
        "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${userId}/${submit}",
        this.state
      )
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };

  render() {
    const { userId, submit1, submit2, submit3 } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.submitHandler}>
          <div>
            <input
              type="text"
              name="userId"
              value={userId}
              onChange={this.changeHandler}
            />
          </div>

          <button value={submit1} onChange={this.changeHandler} type="submit">
            Submit1
          </button>
          <button value={submit2} onChange={this.changeHandler} type="submit">
            Submit2
          </button>
          <button value={submit3} onChange={this.changeHandler} type="submit">
            Submit3
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default PostForm;
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-ptolemy-p1s4i

Comment: Hi, i post an answer to your question, let me know if you have any other issue or if your problem was solved

Comment: Hey, thank you so much for answering, really appreciate it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call the submit method from the onClick method of each submit button, also you had an issue in your jsonplaceholder : you dont need to send the whole route in POST method....just the payload is enough

Also, you do not need the onChange method on a button....i removed them.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
class PostForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      userId: "",
      submit1: "1",
      submit2: "2",
      submit3: "3"
    };
  }

  buildPayload = submitName => {
    return { [`submit${submitName}`]: submitName, userId: this.state.userId };
  };

  changeHandler = e => {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  submitHandler = (submitName) => {
    const payload = this.buildPayload(submitName);
    console.log(payload);
    axios
      .post(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts`, payload)
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
        // If you need the data here so do the following
        console.log(response.data)
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };

  render() {
    const { userId, submit1, submit2, submit3 } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={e => e.preventDefault()}>
          <div>
            <input
              type="text"
              name="userId"
              value={userId}
              onChange={this.changeHandler}
            />
          </div>

          <button
            value={submit1}
            onClick={() => this.submitHandler(this.state.submit1)}
          >
            Submit1
          </button>
          <button
            value={submit2}
            onClick={() => this.submitHandler(this.state.submit2)}
          >
            Submit2
          </button>
          <button
            value={submit3}
            onClick={() => this.submitHandler(this.state.submit3)}
          >
            Submit3
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default PostForm;
```

Output (in console) :

```
{userId: "11", submit1: "1"}
```

In the console

[image: example]

Now if you want, you can also refactor the submit method to an async one....just to make it cleaner :

```
  submitHandler = async (submitName) => {
     const payload = this.buildPayload(submitName);
     const response = await axios.post(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts`, payload)
     console.log(response.data);
  };
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer :D could you please ans this question too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61918624/how-to-map-to-two-apis-in-the-same-jsx-file-react-js , it's regarding the same problem

Comment: I am not able to send my data in the format of payload post(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts`, payload), this is not working for me, also I need to PUT and not post....can you please tell me how to do it in this format      "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?loadId=${this.userId}&eventName=${this.eventName}

Comment: I am using some other api actually, its a PUT api, i cant share it here due to confidentiality reasons...so suppose i had a url like that, and i needed to make a PUT req, how would i send the loadId and eventName to it

Comment: I answer to this question in your second post....please see there and let me know

Comment: would you please update solution for functional component? Thank you