# How to manage differents API endpoints in ReactJS using axios

Tags: reactjs

Here I have my first form, which gives values userid and values 1, 2 or 3 from the submit button..
in the console, like so {userId: "1243", submit: "1"}
so they are posting values to the api   (line 124 in codesandbox)

```
  `.post(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts`, payload)`
```

then I have another form, which three buttons nSubmit1, nSubmit2, and nSubmit3
these are also suppose to send the values in the same format (like this  {userId: "1243", submit: "1"}),

LINE 168 IN PostForm.jsx file

```
  <form>
   <button
            value={submit1}
            onClick={() => this.submitHandler(this.state.submit1)}
          >
            nSubmit1
          </button>
          <button
            value={submit2}
            onClick={() => this.submitHandler(this.state.submit2)}
          >
            nSubmit2
          </button>
          <button
            value={submit3}
            onClick={() => this.submitHandler(this.state.submit3)}
          >
            nSubmit3
          </button>
   </form>
```

but to a diff api, where and how do i define this second api and map my submit values to it...userId is suppose to be common value for both the apis

https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-ptolemy-p1s4i?file=/src/components/PostForm.js

also i need to send pay load in the format of "jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?loadId=${this.userId}&eventName=${this.eventName}"

Comment: if you want to make `userId` accessible to all then simply use `this.setState({ userId })`

Comment: That's not the actual PUT url, I am not able to share the api url due to compnay confidentiality policy. but if u can suppose the url to be a PUT api...how to send userId and eventName in that $ format

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to manage many endpoints in a scallable way, i would suggest you to create a separate file, call it api.js for example, and create different axios instance there :

```
import axios from 'axios'

export const api1 = axios.create({
    baseURL: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/",
    headers: {
        // You can add some headers here like Token....
        Authorization: "Any Auth Token"
    },
})

export const api2 = axios.create({
    baseURL: "https://myOwnApi.com/",
    headers: {
        // You can add some headers here like Token....
        Authorization: "Any Auth Token"
    },
})


export const api3 = axios.create({
    baseURL: "https://AnotherGreatApi.com/",
    headers: {
        // You can add some headers here like Token....
        Authorization: "Any Auth Token"
    },
})
```

Then you can import it in your components

```
import React from "react";
import { api1, api2, api3 } from "./api.js";

class PostForm extends React.Component {
  state = {
    userId: "",
    submit1: "1",
    submit2: "2",
    submit3: "3"
  };

  buildPayload = submitName => {
    return { userId: this.state.userId, [`submit`]: submitName };
  };

  changeHandler = e => {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  submitHandler1 = (api, submitName) => {
    const payload = { userId: this.state.userId, [`submit`]: submitName };
    api.post("/post", payload);
  };

  submitHandler2 = (api, eventName) => {
    const payload = { loadId: this.state.userId, eventName };
    api.put("/someRoute", payload);
  };

  submitHandler3 = (api, anotherParam) => {
    const params = { ID: this.state.userId, anotherParam };
    api.get("/someRoute", params);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={e => e.preventDefault()}>
        <div>
          <input
            type="text"
            name="userId"
            value={this.state.userId}
            onChange={this.changeHandler}
          />
        </div>
        <button  onClick={() => this.submitHandler1(api1, this.state.submit1)}>Submit1</button>
        <button  onClick={() => this.submitHandler2(api2, "eventName1")} >Submit2</button>
        <button onClick={() => this.submitHandler3(api3, this.state.submit3)} >Submit3</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default PostForm
```

Comment: How do i specify that it's a PUT api?

Comment: thanks for your answer, but it gave me an error, please check the sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-christian-g4go0?file=/src/components/PostForm.js

Comment: @user1997 you dont specify that its a "PUT api" ... there is not "PUT api"....PUT is a verb as GET or POST....with axios you just do : ap1.put (as i mentionned)

Comment: oh okay...but i am getting this error "this2.submitHandler is not a function" with ur code...

Comment: this was because you did not export the post form at the end of the file....also there was a typo error on the handler function name. i updated the code...check it out

Answer (score 2):

You could modify the submit handler to accept the API url as a parameter, and store the urls in a constant:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import React from 'react';

const Constants = {
  API1: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/',
  API2: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/',
  API3: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/',
};

class PostForm extends React.Component {
  state = {
    userId: '',
    submit1: '1',
    submit2: '2',
    submit3: '3',
  };

  buildPayload = submitName => {
    return { userId: this.state.userId, [`submit`]: submitName };
  };

  changeHandler = e => {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  }

  submitHandler = (url, submitName) => {
    const payload = this.buildPayload(submitName);
    axios.post(url, payload)
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
      }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={e => e.preventDefault()}>
        <div>
          <input
            type="text"
            name="userId"
            value={this.state.userId}
            onChange={this.changeHandler}
          />
        </div>
        <button onClick={() => this.submitHandler(Constants.API1, this.state.submit1)}>Submit 1</button>
        <button onClick={() => this.submitHandler(Constants.API2, this.state.submit2)}>Submit 2</button>
        <button onClick={() => this.submitHandler(Constants.API3, this.state.submit3)}>Submit 3</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default PostForm;
```

Comment: @user1997 - Apologies. There was some pseudocode in the example. I have fixed this.